# gsub doesn't substitute names in column

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Using R, my data frame capstone3 with column Certificate...HQA has the following levels:

```
levels(capstone3$Certificate...HQA)

 [1] "CUM LAUDE"                     "DIPLOM"                       
 [3] "DOCTORATE"                     "GRADUATE DIPLOMA"             
 [5] "HIGHEST HONS"                  "HONOURS (DISTINCTION)"        
 [7] "HONOURS (HIGHEST DISTINCTION)" "HONS"                         
 [9] "HONS I"                        "HONS II"                      
[11] "HONS II LOWER"                 "HONS II UPPER"                
[13] "HONS III"                      "HONS UNCLASSIFIED"            
[15] "HONS WITH MERIT"               "MAGNA CUM LAUDE"              
[17] "MASTER'S DEGREE"               "OTHER HONS"                   
[19] "PASS DEGREE"                   "PASS WITH CREDIT"             
[21] "PASS WITH DISTINCTION"         "PASS WITH HIGH MERIT"         
[23] "PASS WITH MERIT"               "SUMMA CUM LAUDE"
```

I wrote a code to reduce the number of levels by substituting level [7] with level [9], level [6] with level [12], etc:

```
capstone3$Certificate...HQA <- as.factor(capstone3$Certificate...HQA)

capstone3$Certificate...HQA <- gsub("HONOURS (HIGHEST DISTINCTION)","HONS I", capstone3$Certificate...HQA)

capstone3$Certificate...HQA <- gsub("HONOURS (DISTINCTION)","HONS II UPPER", capstone3$Certificate...HQA)

capstone3$Certificate...HQA <- gsub("HONS WITH MERIT","HONS II LOWER", capstone3$Certificate...HQA)
```

But the above gsub code did not replace the names in the column, could someone kindly point out the problem with my code please?

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses `()` are special characters used in regular expressions to create groups. If you have literal parentheses you need to escape them using `\\`

```
gsub("HONOURS \\(HIGHEST DISTINCTION\\)","HONS I", capstone3$Certificate...HQA)
```

OR as @ManuelBickel: Using `fixed = TRUE` the pattern is a string will be matched as is.

```
gsub("HONOURS (HIGHEST DISTINCTION)","HONS I", capstone3$Certificate...HQA, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: You may also turn on `fixed = TRUE` in `gsub` to make the string be recognized as is without any parsing, e.g., `gsub("HONOURS (HIGHEST DISTINCTION)","HONS I", "HONOURS (HIGHEST DISTINCTION)", fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: @ManuelBickel many thanks for pointing that out.